# Depreciation of local currency and its effect on prices

Tags: exchange-rates, price, food

I have problem with an article Lee H., C. Park, 2013, International Transmission of Food Prices and Volatilities: A Panel Analysis.

Authors wrote:
Difference in log of exchange rates (LOC/ $)- As depreciation of local currency (LOC) against the US dollar will result in higher domestic prices of imported food products in local currency, this variable is expected to carry a positive sign.

Variable (LOC/$) has positive sign in there econometric model. How it is possible?

When exchange rate (LOC/$) rises we have aprreciation of local currency so food prices are lower. I think that the sign should be negative

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting tripped up by notation. Instead of LOC/\$, write \$/LOC, since international trade is most likely to take place using $USD as an intermediary currency.

Here's an example:

Suppose world prices for soybeans are \$150/ton USD.  Today, the Wakandan widget (W) trades at 75W/\$ - so, I suggest rewriting this as $1/75W. Then, absent tariffs, taxes, and other frictions, Wakandans can import US soybeans at 11,250W/ton.

Now suppose the widget depreciates - it now trades at 150W/\$.  Notice that the sign of this change is positive, because you need more LOC to buy a unit of USD.  But if you rewrite as $1/150W, the sign of this change is negative, fitting the intuition that the LOC has become *less* valuable.  And indeed, now Wakandans must pay 22,500W/ton to import US soybeans - a change that would be reflected by a positive sign.

The value change of the LOC is negative, leading to a positive change in the price for imports. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, make sense. I think in this way, but the notation LOC/$ is used several times in this article. Did you read it?

Comment: It's just an inverse of the ratio, and is mathematically consistent either way.  The way I present it is just more in-line with the intuition that is leading to your confusion (and understandably so).  You'll run into this a lot in almost any field - being a good researcher, and writing easily-readable research, are two different skillsets.  Not everyone is a master of both.  :)